# Chrome showing error while doing load testing with Jmeter

Tags: google-chrome, security, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

While I am trying to test an application with Jmeter on chrome as browser, the chrome browser is showing the following error:

> "Your connection is not private"

I have tried importing the security CA certificate but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is (more or less) normal as JMeter generates a self-signed certificate in order to be able to decrypt and record SSL traffic, you need to install the certificate into your browser (or operating system) in order to proceed.

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry for certificate installation instructions for different browsers. Also be aware of fact that as per JMeter 3.2 certificate lives only for 7 days.

Assuming everything goes well you should be able to expand "Advanced" link

[image: JMeter Certificate Error Advanced]

and click "Proceed to %your_application_domain% (unsafe)" link

[image: JMeter proceed unsafe]

---

It might be worth mentioning that there is a non-invasive way of recording a JMeter test which does not assume proxies configuration and certificates installation, check out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) which allows recording JMeter tests directly from Chrome browser without interim steps.